# importing csv with LOAD CSV fails with QueryExecutionKernelException

Tags: csv, neo4j

I'm importing csv using

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///root/rahul/Neo4jData/after_etl_data.csv" AS row
CREATE (:AFTER_ETL_DATA {user_tweet_id:row.user_tweet_id});
```

I'm getting the following error

> QueryExecutionKernelException: Couldn't load the external resource at:
>   file:/root/rahul/Neo4jData/after_etl_data.csv

Things I have done

1) Changed the permission of files to

> 777

2) Chnaged the owner of the file

> ie -rwxrwxrwx 1 neo4j adm  553942876 Sep 12 13:54 after_etl_data.csv

3) Added the line

> dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true

in /etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties

I'm using neo4j 2.2.5

I dont know how to solve this.

Note - However if I start my shell using

> ./neo4j-shell -path graph.db -config
>   /var/lib/neo4j/conf/neo4j.properties

I'm able to insert the data , but since it starts in local mode , I'm unable to view the data in Neo4j UI Interface.

Comment: shouldn't it be `file:///root...` with three slashes?

Comment: I tried with that also , still it fails ! , just edited my question with 3 slashes, anyways i managed to load the data locally , how do i point my local db to point to UI interface  ?